# Make soft keyboard behave like IOS in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout which I placed my widgets proportionally with weight attribute. I don't want to use scrollView, I want my widgets to fit onto screen according to their weights.

However, I want my layout to be scrollable when soft keyboard pops up. I don't want it to be resized so I can't use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

I tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and it moves the edittext field above the soft keyboard. However, this time it does not scroll and I have to close soft keyboard to choose next EditText field.I know that by adding input type, I can have forward buttons on my keyboard. However, I don't want to depend on that only, I also want it to be scrollable without resizing like in IOS.

Can I achieve that? If yes, could you explain this to me , please?

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="20">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagelogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_home" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Tab 1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Tab 2"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Input 1" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Input 1" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Input 1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality isn't built into Android.  If you want that, you need to put your entire layout inside of a scroll view.