# Make soft keyboard scroll view rather than resize it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

I am trying to emulate an iOS-like keyboard for my Android app. Simply put, the contents of my activity should scroll behind the keyboard *without resizing the spacing* (which is what `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` does).

I can achieve a close scroll behavior by making my parent layout a ScrollView (as suggested in [Make soft keyboard behave like IOS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35108444/5748408)), but doing so *also* scrolls my custom action bar (which is an included `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`). Either I am not implementing a custom action bar correctly (so it is *always* at the top of the screen, ignoring scrolling), or there is some trick to get the soft keyboard to only scroll a resize (and scroll) a specific element to make room for itself.

Hopefully this simple picture illustrates what I'm trying to achieve. In the screen on the right, the actionbar is left untouched and the main content spacin remains the same and the view is scrollable.

[image: My desired keyboard scroll behavior]

This is my custom actionbar layout that I include in my activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/primaryRed"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="-7dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/back"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_up_unpadded" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/theGlassFiles"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The current view experiment layout is below. I've tried many things, none of which work. The one below is my latest test, which also does not achieve what I am try to get to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="JoinActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <include
            layout="@layout/actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="362dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="@string/joinMessage"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryBlue"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/form"
            android:layout_width="362dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/message"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.176">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/firstNameHint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/middleName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/middleNameHint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/lastNameHint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/town"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/townHint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/passwordHint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/confirmPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/confirmPasswordHint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/joinButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@color/primaryRed"
                android:text="@string/join"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT**

Swapping around the parent/children layouts, I achieve something *really* close to what I'm aiming for. The actionbar always is on top, and the keyboard only resizes the scroll view. **However**, when I scroll I cannot scroll above the first `EditText` element. Using the picture, I can only scroll up to the first input, and cannot continue to scroll up and see the green icon. Using my actual XML layout, I cannot scroll to see the `TextView` component. Here is the updated layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="JoinActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/actionbar">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="362dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                android:text="@string/joinMessage"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryBlue"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/form"
                android:layout_width="362dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/message"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.464">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/firstNameHint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/middleName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/middleNameHint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/lastNameHint"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/town"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/townHint"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/passwordHint"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/confirmPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/confirmPasswordHint"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/joinButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="49dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:background="@color/primaryRed"
                    android:text="@string/join"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: adjustPan is not what you desire?

Comment: @Raimo adjustPan disables manual scrolling of the background view when the keyboard is visible, so no. I'd like to be able to scroll it myself when the keyboard is up. Also, adjustPan ignores the custom action bar (it scrolls off the screen as I move down editable text fields)

Comment: @Raimo is there a correct way to implement a custom actionbar? I just wanted one where my title text was centered and all caps, and where the word "Back" was next to the `home/back` button indicator on the left. (With as little Java as possible)

Comment: I was totally mistaking, sorry. Don't mind my comment above. Why do you put your actionbar inside the ScrollView though? You should put the ScrollView and the actionbar inside a RelativeLayout or something and put android:layout_below="@id/actionBar" on ScrollView.

Comment: @Raimo see my update. We're almost there, except for the fact that I am not able to scroll and see anything above the first EditText component.

Comment: What's your windowSoftInputMode currently set to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166778/discussion-between-raimo-and-themastergabriel).